# convert java.util.ArrayList to gson.JsonElement

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson, rest-assured

Doing some request to the backend API, for receiving some array with JSON objects which I need to use in test run.
Using RestAssured+Junit5+Gradle+Allure.

```
 Response response = 
 given()
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body(jsonPayload)
 .when()
    .post(STAGINGSCHEDULE+signature)
 .then()
     .assertThat()
     .statusCode(200)
     .body("message", is("Payload valid"),
     "payment_schedule", hasSize(greaterThan(0)))
     .extract().response();
```

I would receive this:

```
ArrayList<JsonElement> jsonElement = response.path("payment_schedule.payment_dates");
```

This command will show me an array filled with json objects which I needed. 
But a cound not convert this to the gson.JsonObject.

```
System.out.println("jsonElement.get(1):   "+jsonElement.get(1));
```

Which methods I used to usually, when generating data by myself. Object is gsonObject, and array is gsonArray

```
callbackJournalObject.add("schedule", scheduleArray);
```

When I try to use

```
callbackJournalObject.add("schedule", jsonElement.get(1));
```

I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonElement
```

JSON Response body example:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Payload valid",
    "payment_schedule": [
        {
            "total": 16800.0,
            "term": 3,
            "payment_dates": [
                {
                    "date": "16.10.2018",
                    "amount": 5600.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "16.11.2018",
                    "amount": 5600.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "17.12.2018",
                    "amount": 5600.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "total": 16650.0,
            "term": 6,
            "payment_dates": [
                {
                    "date": "16.10.2018",
                    "amount": 2800.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "16.11.2018",
                    "amount": 2800.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "17.12.2018",
                    "amount": 2800.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "16.01.2019",
                    "amount": 2800.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "18.02.2019",
                    "amount": 2800.0
                },
                {
                    "date": "18.03.2019",
                    "amount": 2650.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can u show json response?

Comment: added json response body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution worked for me.

```
ArrayList<JsonElement> jsonElement = response.path("payment_schedule.payment_dates");
String jsonElementGet1 = String.valueOf(jsonElement.get(1));
scheduleArray =  (JsonArray)jsonParser.parse(jsonElementGet1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the last comma at the end of the JSON as with it, it's not valid JSON. Once you've done that, try again and see if it works. (Used JSONBlob to verify the validity of the JSON).